# Which apache-beam feature to use to just read a function as first in the pipeline and take the output

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a dataflow pipeline and deploy it in  Cloud environment. I have a code like below, which is trying to read files from a specific folder within a GCS bucket :

```py
def read_from_bucket():
    file_paths=[]
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket("bucket_name")
    blobs_specific = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="test_folder/"))
    for blob in blobs_specific: 
        file_paths.append(blob)       
    return file_paths
```

The above function returns a list of file paths present in that GCS folder.
Now this list is sent to the below code, which will filter the files as per their extension and store it in respective folders in the GCS bucket.

```py
def write_to_bucket():
  
    client = storage.Client()  

    for blob in client.list_blobs("dataplus-temp"):
        source_bucket = client.bucket("source_bucket")
        source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob.name) 
    
        file_extension = pathlib.Path(blob.name).suffix      
        
        if file_extension == ".json":       
               
                destination_bucket=client.bucket("destination_bucket")
                new_blob = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob,destination_bucket,'source_bucket/JSON/{}'.format(source_blob))                         
        
        elif file_extension == ".txt":
           
                destination_bucket=client.bucket("destination_bucket")
                new_blob = source_bucket.copy_blob(source_blob,destination_bucket,'Text/{}'.format(source_blob))
```

I have to execute the above implementation using dataflow pipeline , in such a way that the file path has go to dataflow pipeline and it should get stored in the respective folders. I created a dataflow pipeline like below, but not sure whether I used right Ptrasformations.

```py
pipe= beam.Pipeline()( 
    pipe
    |"Read data from bucket" >> beam.ParDo(read_from_bucket)
    |"Write files to folders" >> beam.ParDo(write_to_bucket)
)

pipe.run()
```

- executed like :

```
python .\\filename.py 
  --region asia-east1 
  --runner DataflowRunner 
  --project proejct_name 
  --temp_location gs://bucket_name/tmp 
  --job_name test
```

I'm getting below error after execution:

```
return inputs[0].windowing
AttributeError: 'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'
```

I have checked apache-beam documentation, but somehow unable to understand. I'm new to apache-beam, just started as a beginner, please consider if this question is silly.

Kindly help me in how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you have to use existing `Beam` [IO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html) to read and write to `Cloud Storage`, example :

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText

def run():
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    (
      p
      | "Read data from bucket" >> ReadFromText("gs://your_input_bucket/your_folder/*")
      | "Write files to folders" >> WriteToText("gs://your_dest_bucket")
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
   logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
   run()
```

Comment: Read data from bucket ***will not just be a single file***, it will be **pile of files ** which get stored into a list and that list has to be sent to  write_to_bucket function., which will handle the writing to bucket as well. You post is taking only one text file from ReadFromText , mine are different extension files

Comment: I need to write datapipe line in such a way that will read the function which returns list and each element in the list will go to write_to folder function , i have executed as per my knowledge, but i'm getting that error which i'm not aware of, kindly help.

Comment: I edited my code to read all the files in a folder

Comment: yes, I got workaround with different approach. @Mazlum Tosun ,Your approach is not utilizing my read function which it has to